# Is it possible to user reduceByKey((x, y, z) => ...)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is it possible to have a reduceByKey of the way: `reduceByKey((x, y, z) => ...)`?

Because I have a RDD:

```
RDD[((String, String, Double), (Double, Double, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double]))]
```

And I want reduce by key and I tried with this operation:

```
reduceByKey((x, y, z) => (x._1 + y._1 + z._1, x._2 + y._2 + z._2, (((x._3)++y._3)++z._3)))
```

and it shows me a error message: `missing parameter type`

Before I tested with two elements and it works, but with 3 I really don't know which is my error. What is the way to do that?

Comment: You probably want `case (x, y, z)` because it's a tuple rather than 3 arguments. Conceivably you might need to give `x`, `y` and `z` explicit types.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're missing, `reduceByKey` is telling you that you have a Key-Value pairing. Conceptually there can only ever be 2 items in a pair, it's part of the what makes a pair a pair. Hence, the full signature of `reduceByKey` can only ever be a 2-Tuple as it's signature. So, no, you can't directly have a function of arity 3, only of arity 2.

Here's how I'd handle your situation:

```
reduceByKey((key,value) =>
  val (one, two, three) = key
  val (dub1, dub2, nameName) = value

  // rest of work
}
```

However, let me make one slight suggestion? Use a `case class` for your value. It's easier to grok and is essentially equivalent to your 3-tuple.

Comment: I got the idea. In your suggestion how I could sum all the values dub1: `dub._1 + dub._2`?

Comment: The expression `val (a, b, c) = x` is actually an `unapply` that "breaks out" the tuple so that `a` is equivalent to `x._1`, i.e. `val (a, b, c) = x` makes "a," "b," and "c" aliases for "x._1," "x._2," and "x._3"

Answer (score 0):

if you see the reduceByKey function on PairRDDFunctions, it looks like,

`def reduceByKey(func: (V, V) => V): RDD[(K, V)]`

hence, its not possible to have it work on a 3-tuple.
However, you can wrap your 3-tuple into a model and still keep your first string as the key making your RDD as RDD[(string, your-model)] and now you can aggregate the model in whatever way you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what is (String, String, Double) representing? Lets call it Foo.                 And lets call (Double, Double, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double])) Bar.  So your RDD is of RDD[(Foo, Bar)] and now you can reduce by your own logic where you just have to handle the logic to add two Bars together.